# Jquery in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I am trying to learn using Jquery in django application.My code looks like this

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from airapp.models import Travel

def search_form(request):
    return render(request, 'search_form.html')


def search(request):
    if 'f' in request.GET and request.GET['f']:
        q = request.GET['f']
        books = Travel.objects.filter(froms__icontains=q)
        return render(request, 'search_results.html',
            {'books': books, 'query': q})
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Please submit a search term.')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from air import views

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^search-form/$', views.search_form),
    url(r'^search/$', views.search),
)
```

**search_form.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/search/" method="get">
        FROM<input type="text" name="f"><br>
        TO<input type="text" name="t"><br>
        CLASS<input type="text" name="c"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**search_results.html**

```
<p>You searched for: <strong>{{ query }}</strong></p>

{% if books %}
    <p>Found {{ books|length }} book{{ books|pluralize }}.</p>
    <ul>
        {% for book in books %}
        <li>{{ book.froms }}</li>
        <li>{{ book.to}}</li>
        <li>{{ book.classs }}</li>
        <li>{{ book.details }}</li>

        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No books matched your search criteria.</p>
{% endif %}
```

When the search result displays it will be on a new html page(search_results.html).I want to display search results on the same html page where form is created(search_form.html) when I click search button.Can I display it using jquery? Can anybody help me write the code.
Also anybody suggest me good tutorial for learning ajax and jquery & how can I use it django 
application development.

Comment: well, in your views, simply render the `search_form.html` instead of results. and in your template don't specify any form action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an working sample. Just need to modify **search_form.html**:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#search-form").submit(function() {
                var from = $("#search-form :input[name='f']").val();
                $.get("/search/", { f : from })
                    .done(function(data) {
                        $("#search-result").html(data);
                        $("#search-result").show();
                    });
                return false;
            })});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="search-form">
        FROM<input type="text" name="f"><br>
        TO<input type="text" name="t"><br>
        CLASS<input type="text" name="c"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>

    <div id="search-result" style="display:none">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, what it does:

1. include jQuery in head
2. in the script, replace 'submit' behaviour of 'search-form': use `$.get` to send a GET request to server, and directly show response in 'search-result' div. (you may modify the codes to make it more robust)
3. in body, create a 'search-result' div for displaying response. Make it invisible by default (may do it in a CSS file)

For Ajax, you may refer to: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. `$.get` is a shortcut based on `$.ajax`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/